# Find the last two digits of $2019^{2019}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Find the last two digits of $2019^{2019}$

I know that you can typically find the last two digits of a number to any power by reducing the number to end with a one and so on (I will show an example of what I am talking about below).

However, $2019$ cannot be reduced such that I will get an even exponent required in this strategy of solving.

So, how do I figure out the last two digits of this equation?

*** Example of the method I referred to ***

Find the last two digits of $41^{2789}$

- Multiply the tens digit of the number (4 here) with the last digit of the exponent (9 here) to get the tens digit. The unit digit will always equal to one.
- $61 (4 × 9 = 36)$. Therefore, 6 will be the tens digit and one will be the unit digit

Keep in mind, I am an algebra 2 student, but my teacher, also a calc teacher, thought I might be able to figure this one out :)

Comment: Hint:  What are the last two digits of 19$^{10}$ ?

Comment: Did you see congruences?

Comment: @Bernard I haven't learned about them, and from what I have been looking into, it seems like I should teach myself them in order to figure this out

Comment: Would you agree that the last two digits of $2019^n$ are the same as those of $19^n$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner interesting, I didn't notice that at first. I only looked into the ones digit, not the tens too. I'm going to look at that more and see if I come up with something. Thanks!

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Is it a coincidence that 19^9 ends in the correct last two digits?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the last two digits of a number by binomial theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/488258/finding-the-last-two-digits-of-a-number-by-binomial-theorem)

Comment: @LeviKline:  No, it is not a coincidence

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Comment: @LeviKline It can be done by the same method you were taught, except we need to account for a negative sign - see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculation shows that the last two digits of $19^5$ are $99$.

Therefore, the last two digits of $19^{10}$ are $01$.

Therefore, the last two digits of $19^{10n}$ are $01$ for $n \in \mathbb N$.

Therefore, the last two digits of $19^{10n+9}$ are same as those of $19^9$, which calculation shows to be 79 (same as those of $19^4 19^5$ or $19^4 99$).

Therefore, the last two digits of $2019 ^ {2019}$ are the same as the answer submitted earlier.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$2019^{2019}=-(1-2020)^{2019}$$

$$=-(1-\binom{2019}12020+\text{terms divisible by}10^2)$$

$=2019\cdot2020-1+100u$(say)

$$=(2000+19)(2000+20)-1+100u$$

$=19\cdot20-1+100v$(say)

Answer (score 0):

Both rules work by applying the Binomial Theorem to $\,(\color{#c00}{\pm1} + 10a)^n$. The rule you mention is the first case below $(\color{#c00}{+1}).\,$ Your example needs the $(\color{#c00}{-1})$ case derived below it - with sign tweaks.

$ \begin{align}(\color{#c00}{+1}+10t+100j)^{\Large u+10j}
&= 1 + (u+10j)(10t+100j) + 100(\cdots)\\
&= 1 + 10tu + 100(\cdots)
\end{align}$

$\begin{align}(\color{#c00}{-1}+10t+100j)^{\Large u+10j}
&= s - s(u+10j)(10t+100j) + 100(\cdots),\ \ \ s = (\color{#c00}{-1})^{\large u}\\
&= s - s 10tu + 100(\cdots)
\end{align}$

$\,(-1+20\color{#0a0}20)^{\large 201\color{#a0f}9}$ has $t=\color{#0a0}2, u = \color{#a0f}9\,$ so $\,s = (-1)^u = -1\,$ therefore

$$ s - s10\color{#0a0}t\color{#a0f}u\, =\, -1 + 10(\color{#0a0}2)\color{#a0f}9\, =\, 179  $$

Therefore the last two digits are $79$.

**Remark** $ $ Unifying both cases yields $\ \bbox[5px,border:1px solid red]{s^{\large u} (1 + 10 stu)}\ $ where $\, s = \color{#c00}{\pm 1}$

See also [this tens digit logarithm law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3101807/242).

Comment: I really like this solution. I don't quite understand it right now but I will definitely review the theorem you referred to and will try working it out a bit more. Thanks for the help!